# I'm getting component "COUNT", "GET_OBJECT", "GET_ARRAY"must be declared error even though the object is declared

Tags: arrays, json, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Below is my stored procedure where I'm trying to hit an endpoint and reading the json response using pl/sql statements. I need to extract the data from the response for which I'm using JSON_OBJECT and JSON_ARRAY. I'm using Oracle 19 and above version and I'm able to access the JSON library. I'm not sure why I'm encountering a PLS-00302 error as component "COUNT", "GET_OBJECT", "GET_ARRAY" must be declared.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ProcessTableauReportMetadata(
 tenant_identifier VARCHAR2
) IS
 -- Declare variables
 offset NUMBER := 0;
 limit NUMBER := 50;
 json_response CLOB;
 totalResults NUMBER;

    -- JSON parsing variables
   json_obj JSON_OBJECT_T;
   items JSON_ARRAY_T;
   item JSON_OBJECT_T;

  -- Data processing variables
   workbook_uuid VARCHAR2(36);
    datasource_uuid VARCHAR2(36);

  BEGIN
       LOOP
      -- Construct endpoint URL with parameters
    endpoint_url := 'https://' || tenant_identifier || '.api.us.devhealtheintent.com/business-    intelligence/v1/reports?biType=TABLEAU&lite=false&offset=' || offset || '&limit=' || limit;

-- Begin HTTP request
req := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST(endpoint_url, 'GET');
UTL_HTTP.SET_TRANSFER_TIMEOUT(100);
UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(req, 'Authorization', 'Bearer ' || 'TOKEN'); -- Replace with actual token

-- Execute HTTP request
resp := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(req);

-- Read the entire JSON response as text
UTL_HTTP.READ_TEXT(resp, json_response);

-- Parse JSON response using built-in JSON parsing functions
json_obj := JSON_OBJECT_T.PARSE(json_response);
items := json_obj.GET_ARRAY('items');

-- Extract totalResults from JSON response
totalResults := json_obj.GET_NUMBER('totalResults');

-- Process each item in the JSON response
FOR i IN 1 .. items.COUNT LOOP
  item := items.GET_OBJECT(i);

  -- Extract workbook_uuid and associatedSources from the item
  workbook_uuid := item.GET_STRING('id');
  associatedSources := item.GET_ARRAY('associatedSources');

  -- Check for non-empty associatedSources
  IF associatedSources.COUNT > 0 THEN
    datasource_uuid := associatedSources.GET_OBJECT(1).GET_STRING('id');

    -- Update datasource_uuid in TABLEAU_USAGE_WORKBOOK_METADATA table
    UPDATE TABLEAU_USAGE_WORKBOOK_METADATA
    SET DATASOURCE_UUID = datasource_uuid
    WHERE WORKBOOK_UUID = workbook_uuid;
  END IF;
END LOOP;

-- Close the HTTP response
UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(resp);

-- Increment offset for the next API call
offset := offset + limit;

-- Exit the loop if totalResults is reached
EXIT WHEN offset >= totalResults;
 END LOOP;

EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
-- Handle exceptions
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: ' || SQLERRM);
UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(resp);
END ProcessTableauReportMetadata;
```

I tried changing the way I have declared JSON_OBJECT and JSON_ARRAY but didn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the missing variable declarations, the problem is that you're treating `items` as if it's a PL/SQL collection type, and it is not. You're also trying to deal with results returned as `json_element_t` as arrays and objects, without explicitly `treat`ing them as such.

You can read more about the JSON data structures and the valid methods you can use for them [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/json-types.html#GUID-BDE10AAA-445B-47B5-8A39-D86C8EA99283).

So instead of:

```
FOR i IN 1 .. items.COUNT LOOP
  item := items.GET_OBJECT(i);
```

use (noticing that the array is indexed from zero, not one as a PL/SQL array would be):

```
FOR i IN 0 .. items.GET_SIZE - 1 LOOP
  item := TREAT(items.GET(i) AS JSON_OBJECT_T);
```

and then instead of:

```
  IF associatedSources.COUNT > 0 THEN
    datasource_uuid := associatedSources.GET_OBJECT(1).GET_STRING('id');
```

use:

```
  IF associatedSources.GET_SIZE > 0 THEN
    datasource_uuid := TREAT(associatedSources.GET(0) AS JSON_OBJECT_T).GET_STRING('id');
```

Skipping the http handling, the data extract part can be done as:

```
-- Process each item in the JSON response
--FOR i IN 1 .. items.COUNT LOOP
FOR i IN 0 .. items.GET_SIZE - 1 LOOP
--  item := items.GET_OBJECT(i);
  item := TREAT(items.GET(i) AS JSON_OBJECT_T);

  -- Extract workbook_uuid and associatedSources from the item
  workbook_uuid := item.GET_STRING('id');
  associatedSources := item.GET_ARRAY('associatedSources');

  -- Check for non-empty associatedSources
--  IF associatedSources.COUNT > 0 THEN
  IF associatedSources.GET_SIZE > 0 THEN
--    datasource_uuid := associatedSources.GET_OBJECT(1).GET_STRING('id');
    datasource_uuid := TREAT(associatedSources.GET(0) AS JSON_OBJECT_T).GET_STRING('id');

    -- Update datasource_uuid in TABLEAU_USAGE_WORKBOOK_METADATA table
    UPDATE TABLEAU_USAGE_WORKBOOK_METADATA
    SET DATASOURCE_UUID = datasource_uuid
    WHERE WORKBOOK_UUID = workbook_uuid;
  END IF;
END LOOP;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7XpGzNbT)